# Is there a replacement for JQuery's .proxy() in React?

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to avoid using JQuery if possible. There is some code I'm reusing that relies on JQuery's $.proxy(func, this). Can I duplicate the functionality in React ?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd need to know more, but the chances are using an arrow function instead of a normal function would make this largely redundant anyway

Comment: The existing code is setInterval($.proxy(this.draw, this), 1000); if that helps

Comment: In this context, what is `draw`? If it's just a function passed in then I think the call to `proxy` is almost certainly redundant, at least when migrating to React

Comment: It would also be helpful to produce a runnable snippet of the React component you're working on. Stack Overflow supports that for Javascript

Comment: @MatthewDaly yes it seems just calling draw.bind(this) worked fine.